# PHP Email Form using checkboxes

Tags: php

This is a part of my form I am trying to email. I want to be able to see which answer the user checks and email that form submission to myself. I can't use anything other than a check box, because I am adding information to Constant Contact lists.

```
<label for="agegroup">What age group are you in?</label><br/>

<input type="checkbox"  value="Teens" name="Lists[]" id="list_Teens" />
<label for="list_Teens"><img src="http://theswagsociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/teen.png" alt="teen age group" width="239" height="77" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5892" /></label>

<input type="checkbox"  value="20\'s" name="Lists[]" id="list_20\'s" />
<label for="list_20\'s"><img src="http://theswagsociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/20.png" alt="20 somethings" width="255" height="79" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5895" /></label>

<input type="checkbox"  value="30\'s" name="Lists[]" id="list_30\'s" />
<label for="list_30\'s"><img src="http://theswagsociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/30.png" alt="30 somethings" width="257" height="79" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5897" /></label>

<input type="checkbox"  value="40\'s" name="Lists[]" id="list_40\'s" />
<label for="list_40\'s"><img src="http://theswagsociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/40.png" alt="40 somethings" width="257" height="79" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5898" /></label>

<input type="checkbox"  value="50\'s" name="Lists[]" id="list_50\'s" />
<label for="list_50\'s"><img src="http://theswagsociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/50.png" alt="50 somethings" width="256" height="79" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5900" /></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only check boxes checked by the user will be submitted and other check boxes values will not be available in php.

you can use...

```
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['submit_email'])){
         extract($_POST);    // this will extract all posted data as variables

         if(isset($list)){   // checks if any checkbox is checked
              foreach($list as $item){       // loop all the checked checkedboxes
                  //here you can strore the value in string or the way you want to format
              }
         }
     }
```